# Does placing of anchor tag impacts seo rank better than presenting same content to the user in a pop up

Tags: seo

We have a new cars website where people come to check prices of various cars in cities in the USA.

For example:

```
example.com/bmw-in-newyork

example.com/bmw-in-newjersey

example.com/audi-in-seattle
```

We are planning to increase the SEO traffic on this page. For this, we are planning to put these links on model pages of the website.

For example: On BMW page (example.com/bmw/), we will put anchor tags for example.com/bmw-in-newyork, example.com/bmw-in-newjersey, example.com/bmw-in-seattle.

We were planning to put anchor tag like following:

```
 Text: Check the price of BMW in new jersey.

 Anchor link: example.com/bmw-in-newjersey.
```

But we were thinking would it make sense to navigate the user to a bmw-in-newjersery page if the user clicks on "Check price of BMW in new jersey."

The user would expect us to show the price in pop up or upfront and not to move to a different page when he clicks on this link. But we have got SEO advice from someone that SEO of page would only boost through anchor tag implementation and not by showing the price in the popup.

Is this correct? What should we do in such cases where SEO and user experience are going in different direction?

Comment: The typical UI for clicking on a link on the web is moving to a different page.  Why would your users expect a different experience in this instance?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: But this increases the exit rate of the pages and there are few information that user would like to see on the pop-up/tooltip itself